# Display target value for week when targets are in 4 week increments

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a targets table which goes up in increments of 4 weeks like so

| Week | Target |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 |
| 5 | 67890 |
| 9 | 12345 |

I then have a calendar table from which I would display all 52 weeks of a year. I would like to list the target for the higher week where the week number is between 2 week numbers. E.g. Week 4 will use the target for week 5 as it is between 1 & 5.

I have tried CTEs and left joins but this will not bring back every number in the calendar table, only those found in the target table. I have also tried cross apply and a number of ways to join. I am stumped at this point

Answer (score 0):

You can just `join` with arithmetic:

```
select . . . 
from calendar c join
     targets t
     on ceiling((c.week - 1) / 4.0) * 4 + 1 = t.week
```

Comment: Forgive me if im missing something but how would this work for for example with week 12? 

ceiling(12 / 4.0) * 4 = 12 which would be a non-existent target bracket

Comment: @Chaddeus . . . I adjusted the answer.